# Footer content cannot get margin in new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a simple footer content that have this structure:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <p>System developed by a developer</p> |
        <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
            english
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I've applied this css:

```
#footer
{
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer *
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Essentially what I did is stick the footer at the bottom of the page, and I tried to get the content of the footer in one line. This working nice, but when I resize the page, the footer content is disposed in a new line (if there is no space enough for the other item in the footer), the problem's that the new line does not get the left margin that I've set `15px` what I can do for this?

*Example:*

[image]

I put a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23745/).

Note that I'm also using `Bootstrap`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` is not in any element, its plain text. That way the `*` in your CSS doesn't catch it.

Old and new example next to eachother:

The only difference is the `div` surrounding the `|`.

```css
#footer
{
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

#footer *
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#footer2
{
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}

#footer2 *
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <p>System developed by a developer</p> |
        <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
            english
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer2">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <p>System developed by a developer</p> 

        <div>
            |        <!-- Over here -->
        </div>

        <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
            english
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks got it, but I really need to create a div each time that I must add a separator?

Comment: @user3287550 Yes, if you want the space between elements this is the most clean way to do that. I would personally make it more expressive and create the tag like `<div class="seperator">|</div>` to make sure you know what you are doing there a year after development. Now, your site may be small, but in large projects that helps so much!

Comment: there is a separator of bootstrap available?

Comment: @user3287550 I don't know of a bootstrap equivelent. What do you mean the same problem?

Comment: Try to reduce the window until the span go to new line, seems that does not get the margin

Comment: @user3287550 Try to set the style of that span to `display:block;` - span usually is `display:inline;` wich doesn't work together with margin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121064/discussion-between-user3287550-and-randy).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieved something like this

```css
#footer
{
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    border-top: 1px solid #337ab7;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer *
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
}
span#select-language {
    margin-left:10px;
   }  
 #footer p{padding-top:0px}

@media only screen and (max-width:350px) {
    #footer p{width:65%; padding-top: 0; float:left;}
span#select-language {
    margin-left:10px;
   }  
  #footer-content {
    width: 100%;
   }
    

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <p>System developed by a developer</p> |
        <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
            english
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```